# Can a custom stream throw its own custom exceptions or should it only throw IOException?

Tags: c#, exception, stream

I have my own Connection class and a ConnectionStream class which essentially just wraps the Connection's send/receive methods.

The Connection send/receive methods can throw exceptions like ServerClosedConnException or NetworkShutdownException

Should my Stream be catching these and wrapping them in IOException (using innerException), or can it just let them bubble up to the user (with some try-finally to handle cleanup ofcourse)

I see in the .NET framework, the NetworkStream wraps any errors from the Socket in an IOException

Comment: No.  The .NET Stream derived classes don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stream base class acts as the defacto contract for its subclasses.  If you are planning on exposing your subclass in a public API, it would be considerate to abide by the documented behaviour for the Stream class, since the user of your subclass might be blissfully unaware of its particular type.  For example, if you wish to abide by the contract of the Read method, your implementation shouldn't be exposing any exceptions that aren't of a type listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.

However, this doesn't mean that you can't use more specific exception types.  If you have reason to create a custom exception type anyway (assuming you think this is a good idea after reading the [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) mentioned by JerKimball), it could potentially be a subclass of IOException.  However, this probably shouldn't be necessary unless users of your Stream subclass are likely to want to do something besides logging with the exception details.

Comment: The System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream class wraps any SocketExceptions which occur in an IOException. There doesn't appear to be any reason for this other than what you've said about a defacto contract. Do you think I should be aiming to have my ConnectionStream class be just as reusable as the NetworkStream class? Or is that just me being pedantic?

Comment: That depends on who will be using your subclass.  If it's part of a public API that will be used outside your immediate working group, then conforming to the expected contract for a Stream would be "polite".  Imagine yourself as a developer who is using an instance of your subclass typed as a Stream and provided via dependency injection: what would you like the class to do with a connectivity-related exception?

Comment: This answer was very very helpful thank you. I decided to let my Stream throw the connection exception.

Answer (score 3):

Don't catch exceptions unless you intend to *handle* them.  They will bubble up the call stack until an upstream handler catches and handles them, or the program terminates.

If your Connection class is throwing a very specific exception like `ServerClosedConnException` or `NetworkShutdownException`, and you catch that and rethrow a *less specific* `IOException`, I don't see how that is adding any value.

Comment: Thanks. But then why would the .NET NetworkStream class wrap SocketExceptions in an IOException when a call to read/write fails?

Comment: Hmm maybe it does throw SocketException, for some reason I remember it wrapping the exception. I will test it right now.

Comment: Maybe because, by rethrowing, they don't expose implementation details of the underlying class.

Comment: And that's what I'm concerned about. I want my stream to be just as reusable as NetworkStream. I don't know if I'm being dumb or not.

Comment: And I've just tested the NetworkStream class, it does indeed wrap SocketExceptions inside IOException.

Comment: A `SocketException` might be meaningful to the `NetworkStream` class, but it might not necessarily be meaningful to the *consumer* of the `NetworkStream` class.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to let exceptions bubble up **unless** you have more details to add **or** you can handle the exception yourself.  In the first case your throw a new exception with the actual exception as the `InnerException`.

Read [Wrapping Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in MSDN.

In your case I would let it just bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the Exception Guidelines say:

[ref]

- [Designing Custom Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Choosing the Right Type of Exception to Throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229021%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The most relevant portion:

```
Do throw the most specific (the most derived) exception that is appropriate. 
For example, if a method receives a null (Nothing in Visual Basic) argument, 
it should throw System.ArgumentNullException instead of its base type 
System.ArgumentException.
```

I would extrapolate that to also mean in your case, the most detailed exception is the "correct" one to propogate; making a few assumptions about your exception types, they are probably the "correct" one to propogate, *possibly* wrapped in a "ConnectionException" custom exception.

That said, I do see how it would "make sense" to consider wrapping it in an `IOException`, since that is the "shape" of the exception; but in cases where I disagree with the guidelines and I go my way, it usually bites me later down the road. :)